# Google API Server to Server Authentication returns an empty array?

Tags: php, laravel-4, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

I am trying to access an email calendar using server to server authentication , i managed to get a token but when i use `$service->calendarList->listCalendarList()->getItems()` it returns an empty array, and i am sure that there is a calendars there

Note : I am using laravel and i am already added my api key in the security option of Google Admin (wide range domain)

```
class Calendar {
private static $clientId;
private static $emailAddress;
private static $certificateFingerprints;
private static $p12;
private static $scopes;
private static $p12Password;
private static $sub;
private static $grantType;
private static $client;

public static function initiate(){
    self::$clientId = $_ENV["google_clientId"];
    self::$emailAddress = $_ENV["google_email"];
    self::$certificateFingerprints = $_ENV["google_certificate_fingerprints"];
    self::$p12 = file_get_contents(storage_path("keys/trotride.p12"));
    self::$scopes = array(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
        "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/"
    );
    self::$p12Password = "notasecret";
    self::$sub = "mail@domain.net";
    self::$grantType = "http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer";
}
public static function connect(){
    self::initiate();

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("AppName");
    $client->setClientId(self::$clientId);

    $token = Session::get("token");
    if(isset($token)){
        $client->setAccessToken($token);
    }

    $credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        self::$emailAddress,
        self::$scopes,
        self::$p12,
        self::$p12Password,
        self::$grantType,
        self::$sub
    );

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);

    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
    }

    if($client->getAccessToken()){
        Session::set("token",$client->getAccessToken());
        self::$client = $client;

        $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($service->calendarList->listCalendarList()->getItems());
        echo "</pre>";

    }else{
        echo "failed";
    }

}}
```

Variable $_ENV["google_email"] contain the *********@developer.gserviceaccount.com email address

Comment: Did you add service account email address to the calendar? In the Calendar Settings-> Calendars tab, find the calendar you want to access and click on “Shared: Edit settings” add the service account email address.This will give the service account the same access as if you where sharing it with any other user. Also, check in the API explorer whether you are able to list the calendar. Here is the link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Comment: Thank you so much, but actually i have solved it, i am using wide domain range with google admin,i just have deleted the client credentials from my google console and made a new one, and added my new credentials to the Manage API client access option in google admin and now it works the code was fine ^_^ , Thank you so much for your help ^_^